# django save all record in for loop

Tags: django

[image]

this is the code from the picture

```
  {% for schedule in sched %}
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>{{schedule.Remark}}</td>
<td>Php {{ schedule.Amount|floatformat:2}}</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

this is the code from inserting record to database

```
 id = request.POST.get('ids')
    educlevel = request.POST.get('gradelevel')

studentname = StudentProfile(id=id)
educationlevel = EducationLevel(id=educlevel)

id = request.POST.get('payments')
payment = PaymentType(id=id)

sc = request.POST.get('schoolyear')
schoolyear = SchoolYear(id=sc)
V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord(
        Student_Users=studentname, Payment_Type=payment,
        Education_Levels=educationlevel,School_Year=schoolyear
    )
V_insert_data.save()
for file in request.FILES.getlist('myfile'):
    StudentsSubmittedDocument.objects.create(
        Students_Enrollment_Records=V_insert_data,
        Document=file
    )
insert_StudentsPaymentSchedule = StudentsPaymentSchedule(
        Students_Enrollment_Records =  V_insert_data,
        #Amount = ScheduleOfPayment.Amount,
        Remarks = ScheduleOfPayment.Remark
    )
insert_StudentsPaymentSchedule.save()
```

this the models.py

```
class ScheduleOfPayment(models.Model):
    Pending_Request = [
       ('Active', 'Active'),
       ('Inactive', 'Inactive'),
    ]
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Amount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    Remark = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True, null=True)
```

this is where I want to save all the record shown

```
class StudentsPaymentSchedule(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records=models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Payment_Schedule = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Amount = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Remarks=models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
```

this is the problem, only 1 record save in database StudentsPaymentSchedule, I just want to save all the Payment schedule and amount from database ScheduleOfPayment and automatic post it in StudentsPaymentSchedule

and I don't know what this mean

django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7fb81fd32048

[image]

UPDATE

I tried this code from my views

```
teachers = ScheduleOfPayment.objects.filter(Payment_Type=StudentsEnrollmentRecord.Payment_Type, Education_Levels = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.Education_Levels)
    for each in teachers:
      insert_StudentsPaymentSchedule = StudentsPaymentSchedule(
              Students_Enrollment_Records =  V_insert_data,
              #Amount = ScheduleOfPayment.Amount,
              Remarks = each
          )
      insert_StudentsPaymentSchedule.save()
```

and I receive this error

[image]

Comment: please don't delete question and post it again, you can always edit your question for better explanation  so people have better chance of answering it. Edited question will be bump to the top. If that doesn't work put a bounty on it

Comment: cause i don't have bounty